# I need to identify when a series of binary numbers transition based on conditions for a pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a new column to identify cells based on the following conditions:

1. when a cell on the column TARGET contains the number one
2. when the cell on the column TARGET that contains the number one is followed by cells containing 6 zeros in a row.

Let me try to exemplify, I have a table that looks like this:

| CLI_CD | TARGET |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |

What I need is to create a new column named OUTPUT that identifies the transition of numbers, assigning the value TRUE only when the conditions are met, and this assigning needs to be done on the last occurrence of the number one. The column should behave like this:

| CLI_CD | TARGET | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | False |
| 3 | 1 | False |
| 3 | 1 | True |
| 3 | 0 | False |
| 3 | 0 | False |
| 3 | 0 | False |
| 3 | 0 | False |
| 3 | 0 | False |
| 3 | 0 | False |
| 3 | 0 | False |

What I have tried so far looks like this:

```
def verify(df):
    df['OUTPUT'] = df['TARGET'].rolling(6).sum().eq(0).shift(-6) & df['TARGET'].eq(1)
    return df

df = df.groupby('CLI_CD').apply(verify)
```

Even though the solution works, I'm not sure WHY it works and also if it is the best way to implement the solution. I wanted to check with you guys to see whether there is a more efficient or even correct way to implement it.

Comment: Which parts are you confused about? E.g. `df['TARGET'].eq(1)` should be obvious, but maybe you're confused about the offsets `6` and `-6` you're using? Or maybe you're confused by the way assignment/return works? Which, BTW, is justified because [this is not good design](/q/13062423/4518341 "Is making in-place operations return the object a bad idea?"). If I were you, I'd return the new column and let the handler assign it. Also, I just edited to improve the code readability, if that helps.

Comment: FWIW, you could simplify the conditions in natural language: "when a cell on the column TARGET contains the number one **and** is followed by cells containing 6 zeros in a row."

Comment: @wjandrea what is making me confused is the .rolling(6) and .shift(-6). I am quite sure that this is not the best way to write this code. That's why I came here to ask for different solutions and points of view. Thanks for editing the question.

Comment: Just to add to the "not good design" I mentioned, there's a more specific thing for Pandas: [`.groupby().apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html): "Functions that mutate the passed object can produce unexpected behavior or errors and are not supported."

Comment: `.rolling()` puts the result at the **end** of the sequence by default, that's why you need to `.shift(-6)`. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-sliding-window-view):

Description (Thanks **@wjandrea**!):

This snippet lets you specify the ***pattern*** you want to look for in the data, i.e. "a one followed by six zeroes", here written as `np.array([1, *[0]*6])` (this is the `arr=` argument in the transforming function). This can generalize to patterns where a sum wouldn't help, like say `0100110`.

```py
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view


def fn(g, arr=np.array([1, *[0] * 6])):
    x = (sliding_window_view(g, len(arr)) == arr).all(1)
    return np.pad(x, (0, len(g) - len(x)), constant_values=0)


df["OUTPUT"] = df.groupby("CLI_CD")["TARGET"].transform(fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   CLI_CD  TARGET  OUTPUT
0       3       1   False
1       3       1   False
2       3       1    True
3       3       0   False
4       3       0   False
5       3       0   False
6       3       0   False
7       3       0   False
8       3       0   False
9       3       0   False
```

Comment: It'd help to add a description of how this works, like say, *'This lets you specify the **pattern** you want to look for in the data, i.e. "a one followed by six zeroes", here written as `np.array([1, *[0]*6])`. This can generalize to patterns where a sum wouldn't help, like say 0100110.'* You can use that if you want :)

Comment: Why convert to int? It works fine if you remove `.astype(int)`, no?

Comment: @wjandrea It works, but you get boolean series (`True`/`False`). But yes, you can convert the whole column to `1`/`0` as the final step. (Thanks for the description - I add it to the answer).

Comment: That's what I mean: OP wants a boolean series

Comment: @wjandrea Oh, you're right.. my bad then :) I've removed the `.astype(int)` part.